# Facebook token log out invalidation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to know if a user that logs out of Facebook even with 60 days access token (long lived) invalidates the token and I cannot access the user information.

If so, is there any way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure they're expiring on logout? We've seen them expire on password change but not on logout...

Comment: Thanks for the reply... "Calling FB.logout will also invalidate the access token that you have for the user, unless you have extended the access token. More info on how to extend the access token here."

Comment: Why are you calling `FB.logout`? That's different than the user just logging out of Facebook.com, and rarely necessary.

Comment: When a user logs out of Facebook, the access token is still valid?. Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146686/how-can-i-make-it-so-logging-out-doesnt-invalidate-my-facebook-access-token.

Comment: My last tests, admittedly about four months ago, resulted in access tokens still working after a direct Facebook.com logout.

Comment: Are you using the `offline_access` permission ?

Comment: I believe it does not exist anymore the `offline_access`

Comment: I saw this in the Facebook documentation. "On all the platforms it will also invalidate any access token that you have for the user that was issued before the logout." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout
Does this invalidates extended user access tokens (60 days)?